# SQL Select query to select the most rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * from tickets 
where status = 'Completed' 
and DATE(closed_timestamp) = '2014-04-25' 
group by assigned_to
```

i want to show the `assigned_to` column that has the most rows with a status of 'Completed' and where the `closed_timestamp` date is today

how can i make sure it shows the `assigned_to` with the most rows?

Comment: Apply an `ORDER BY [some count field] DESC LIMIT 1` clause at the end.  BTW, you should consider using something like `WHERE closed_timestamp BETWEEN '2014-04-25 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-25 23:59:59'` in your where clause, as it would allow you to use an index on `closed_timestamp` whereas `DATE(closed_timestamp)` would disallow use of an index.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming "today" is the date in the question, is this what you want?

```
SELECT assigned_to
from tickets 
where status = 'Completed' and DATE(closed_timestamp) = '2014-04-25' 
group by assigned_to
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count (whatever your primary key column is) as number 
from tickets where status = 'Completed' and DATE(closed_timestamp) = '2014-04-25' 
group by assigned_to
order by number desc
LIMIT 1;
```

This will count the number of IDs that have the same assigned_to value and limit it to the first result.

Comment: it would have to be `order by count(primarykey)` not `order by number`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select assigned_to, count(*) records
from etc
group by assign_to
order by records desc
limit 1
```